# Copy all elements in RDD to Array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So, I'm reading data from a JSON file and creating a DataFrame. Usually, I would use

```
sqlContext.read.json("//line//to//some-file.json")
```

Problem is that my JSON file isn't consistent. So, for each line in the file, there are 2 JSONs. Each line looks like this

```
{...data I don't need....}, {...data I need....}
```

I only need my `DataFrame` to be formed from the data I need, i.e. the second JSON of each line. So I read each line as a string and substring the part that I need, like so

```
val lines = sc.textFile(link, 2)
val part = lines.map( x => x.substring(x.lastIndexOf('{')).trim)
```

I want to get all the elements in 'part' as an `Array[String]` then turn the `Array[String]` into one string and make the DataFrame. Like so

```
val strings = part .collect() //doesn't work
val strings = part.take(1000) //works
val jsonStr = "[".concat(strings.mkString(", ")).concat("]")
```

The problem is, if I call `part.collect()`, it doesn't work but if I call `part.take(N)` it works. However, I'd like to get all my data and not just the first N.

Also, if I try `part.take(part.count().toInt)` it still doesn't work.

Any Ideas??

**EDIT**

I realized my problem after a good sleep. It was a silly mistake on my part. The very last line of my input file had a different format from the rest of the file.

So `part.take(N)` would work for all N less than `part.count()`. That's why `part.collect()` wasn't working.

Thanks for the help though!

Comment: start by sharing example data and expected output.

Comment: please clarify - what exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Do you see and exception (if so - add it to the post)? Do you get unexpected results (same - add them)?

Comment: and - the approach of reading the RDD into an Array and then turning that array into a DataFrame is *wrong* - it won't work if your data is large, and if it isn't - why use Spark in the first place? You should transform the RDD into a DataFrame directly, or work solely with DataFrames.

Comment: as @TzachZohar said you are abusing Spark. Take everything into an RDD and/or dataframe and use Spark itself to separate what you need

Comment: How would i go about converting an RDD[Strings] to a dataframe??